# Como escrever em um arquivo txt em Python?

Tags: python, arquivo, txt

Como abrir um arquivo txt e adicionar o conteúdo de alguma variável nele?
Por exemplo, um conteúdo que sai do print no código abaixo.

```py
for passw in senha_list:
    print(passw,end='')
```

Comment: É importante tentar entender o conceito de arquivo antes. https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files Na documentação oficial do Python tem bem explicado como abrir, fechar e escrever em um arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para gravar os dados em arquivo, basta usar o comando `open` do python, nele devemos passar como parâmetro o nome do arquivo que deseja salvar assim como o `modo` como deseja abrir o arquivo no sistema de arquivos, você pode ver a [documentação aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Segue um exemplo da utilização de acordo com o exemplo que passou:

```
with open('saida.txt','w') as f:
    for passw in senha_list:  
        f.write('{}\n'.format(passw))
```

Neste exemplo estamos gravando um elemento `passw` por linha dentro do arquivo `saida.txt`, para isso eu usei o método string format, para mais informações como funciona o format, [segue a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format).

Answer (score -2):

```
f = open('saida.txt','at')
for passw in senha_list:
    f.write(f'{}\n')
f.close()
```